# Error en cadena de caracteres en C

Tags: array, c

Estoy empezando a programar y me surgió la siguiente duda al cargar una cadena de caracteres.........

Cuando ingreso 1 o dos caracteres no pasa nada, pero al ingresar por ejemplo 50 caracteres me genera error y se cierra al momento de ingresar otro carácter en la consola.

Al depurar me sale cadena[i] = < error; cannot access memory at address 0x6d966c0c>`

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define MAX 5
int validar(char[]);
int main(){

int repetir,r,i;
char cadena[MAX];//cadena para el texto

printf("\t\tEL TEXTO NO PUEDE SER MAYOR A 20 CARACTERES\n\n\n");

while(repetir!=1){      
        
  for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
     
     do{
            
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\t\tIngrese el texto: ");
        scanf("%s",cadena);     
        r=validar(cadena);//retorna el valor de la funcion validar  
                    
     }while(r==0 || strlen(cadena)>1);  
        
  }
    
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        
        printf("%s \n",cadena[i]);
        
    }
    
        
    printf("\n\n\n\t\tPara finalizar presione 1/otra tecla para repetir: 
");
    scanf("%d",&repetir);   
    
}
getch();
}
int validar(char cadena[MAX]){
int i;  
for(i=0;i<strlen(cadena);i++){      
    if(strlen(cadena)>1){   
        printf("\n\n\t\tINGRESE SOLO UN CARACTER\n\n");
        return 0;
    }       
        if(isalpha(cadena[i])){
        
        if(i==strlen(cadena))
        return 1;
            
    }   
    else{   
        printf("\n\n\t\tINGRESE ALGO VALIDO\n\n");
        return 0;
        }   
}

}
```

Comment: Por favor añade el código. Esa imagen sola no dice nada del problema...

Comment: Esto es para `C++` o `C`? No es una cosa trivial

Comment: MAX está muy pequeño (5) su string solo soporta 4 caracteres máximos (NULL es él último) - así, cambie para un valor mayor (e.g. 51 para 50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se trata de un error clásico, un *buffer oferrun*. Estás reservando un espacio de memoria para la cadena que es de sólo 5 caracteres. Al intentar colocar más de los que caben el programa termina escribiendo sobre una zona de memoria que no la tiene reservada.

Siempre es necesario chequear que no se intente escribir fuera de los límites de los datos, de lo contrario esos errores a veces son muy difíciles de detectar. En programas para PC/Linux/Mac a veces es más fácil, pero en programas para micro-controladores es una verdadera pesadilla.

Una manera de mejorar algo tu código es definir las siguientes macros:

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s
```

Es una técnica que se llama *stringify*. Funciona en los compiladores que yo utilizo. Si no te funciona en el que estás utilizando deberás buscar el equivalente.

Luego adaptar donde imprimes el mensaje al usuario con la longitud máxima de la cadena para indicar la cantidad máxima real de caracteres que admites:

```
printf("\t\tEL TEXTO NO PUEDE SER MAYOR A " xstr(MAX) " CARACTERES\n\n\n");
```

Y finalmente usar una técnica similar para especificar en `scanf` la cantidad máxima admitida de caracteres:

```
scanf("%" xstr(MAX) "s",cadena);
```

El uso de la combinación de macros `xstr(s)` y `str(s)` es debido a que no existe una manera de convertir directamente un argumento de una macro a una constante de texto, y por eso es necesario utilizar dos niveles de macro.

La macro `str(s)` convierte a constante de cadena (*C string*) su argumento `s`. Por ejemplo, si utilizamos `str(MAX)`, `MAX` definido como `#define MAX 5`, el preprocesador lo expanderá como `"MAX"`. El preprocesador simplemente adicionará las comillas `"` antes y después del argumento `s` de la macro (también elimina espacios en blanco, etc.). Si pones, por ejemplo `str("123")`, lo expandirá como `"\"123\""`.

Al utilizar dos niveles de macro se garantiza que el argumento `s` de la macro `xstr` sea expandido por el preprocesador antes de expandir a la propia macro. De esta forma, el argumento `s` de la macro `str` lo que recibe es ya ya una expansión del argumento `s` de la macro `xstr`, en el caso de tu código, la expansión de la macro `MAX`, que es `5`, y dando como resultado final la constante `"5"`.

La expansión final de la llamada a `printf` quedará así:

```
printf("\t\tEL TEXTO NO PUEDE SER MAYOR A " "5" " CARACTERES\n\n\n")
```

La forma en que se concatenan las cadenas al compilar el código de la llamada a las funciones `printf` y `scanf` es estándar en **C**, de eso se encarga ya el compilador.

Comment: Interesante técnica pero solo para aclarar: El operador `#` es un operador del preprocesador que está en la especificación del estándar [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) (página 185, 6.10.3.2). Entonces esas dos macros deberían de funcionar en cualquier compilador que cumpla con el estándar. También sería bueno que en la respuesta expliques como realmente funciona esas dos macros, por ejemplo, porque no podría usar solamente la macro `str` en vez de `xstr`. Esto aumenta la calidad de la respuesta.

Comment: @MrDave1999, gracias por el comentario. Mejoraré la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #define MAX 5
> ```

Esto es una directiva de pre-procesador. Cuando el pre-procesador vea el texto `MAX` lo reemplazará con un `5`.

> ```
> char cadena[MAX];//cadena para el texto
> ```

Esto es una declaración de formación<sup>1</sup> de caracteres con `MAX` elementos, sabemos que tiene tamaño cinco por la directiva de pre-procesador que hemos visto antes.

> ```
> printf("\t\tEL TEXTO NO PUEDE SER MAYOR A 20 CARACTERES\n\n\n");
> ```

Eso es una mentira. El texto puede ser tan grande como soporte la memoria del ordenador, pero tú pretendes leer sobre una formación<sup>1</sup> en la que sólo caben hasta cinco (`MAX`) caracteres, por eso...

> al ingresar por ejemplo 50 caracteres me genera error y se cierra al momento de ingresar otro carácter en la consola

Es normal que el programa falle de manera catastrófica si en un espacio de cinco caracteres intentas ingresar, por ejemplo, 50.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.